# Creating a handler for remote JSON file

Tags: node.js, json, handler, api-design

I currently have a data handler for a remote JSON file, that gets updated on the server every 2 minutes, the handler downloads the JSON file and it has some methods within it that can get different pieces of information from it. The handler, minus the methods that return the data, is as follows

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class DataHandler extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.shouldUpdate.bind(this);
    }

    updateTimer = setInterval(this.update.bind(this), 120000);

    async shouldUpdate() {
        if (!fs.existsSync('vatsimData.json')) await this.initialUpdate();

        const file = fs.readFileSync('vatsimData.json');
        const parsed = JSON.parse(file);
        const oldDT = Date.parse(parsed.updated_date);

        const dateDifference = Date.now() - oldDT;
        const minutes = Math.floor(dateDifference / 60000);

        if (minutes >= 2) await this.update();

        return false;
    }

    async update() {
        fs.copyFile('vatsimData.json', 'oldData.json', (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });
        let body = await this.downloadFile();
        const parsedJSON = JSON.parse(body);

        parsedJSON.updated_date = new Date();
        const json = JSON.stringify(parsedJSON);
        fs.writeFileSync('vatsimData.json', json, function(err, result) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
        });
        const oldFile = fs.readFileSync('oldData.json');
        const newFile = fs.readFileSync('vatsimData.json');
        const oldParsed = JSON.parse(oldFile);
        const newParsed = JSON.parse(newFile)
        const diff = compareJson.map(oldParsed, newParsed);
        const result = {}
        for (const {type, data} of Object.values(diff.controllers)) {
            if (result[type]) {
                result[type].push(data)
             } else {
                result[type] = [data]
             }
        }
        if (result.created) {
            this.emit('newController', result.created)
        }
    }

    async initialUpdate() {
        let body = await this.downloadFile();
        const parsedJSON = JSON.parse(body);

        parsedJSON.updated_date = new Date();
        const json = JSON.stringify(parsedJSON);
        fs.writeFileSync('vatsimData.json', json, function(err, result) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
        });
    }

    downloadFile() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const urlList = [
                'http://us.data.vatsim.net/vatsim-data.json',
                'http://eu.data.vatsim.net/vatsim-data.json',
                'http://apac.data.vatsim.net/vatsim-data.json'
            ];
            const url = urlList[Math.floor(Math.random()*urlList.length)];
            request(url, (error, response, body) => {
                if (error) reject(error);

                if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
                    reject('Invalid status code <' + response.statusCode + '>');
                }

                resolve(body);
            });
        });
    }

    async loadFile(){
        await this.shouldUpdate();
        return(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('vatsimData.json', {encoding:'utf-8'})));
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make this any more efficient as I am not sure this is the best way that I can do it.

Comment: This is probably too open-ended and needs focus to be useful to other users and actually get answered on SO.

Comment: @DrCord what would you recommed to make it more specific?

Comment: The specific problems you would like to solve rather than "make it cleaner". for example: if you want it to run faster. The word "cleaner" in this context is much too open - what it means to you might not be what others think... Maybe you are trying to reduce the number of lines of code, maybe trying to improve speed, maybe trying to use more built in functionality in the language... etc.

Comment: I've updated it now

Comment: What specific parts do you think need optimization?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just feel like it is not as efficient as it could be

Comment: without a more specific question I fear you will get little traction on SO. I will point you to the documentation for how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I do hope someone is able to help you and wish you good luck.